Parts get deleted when I run and camera is scripted in Roblox Studio
The issue is that when I script a camera to move in 1 direction, all the parts get deleted for no reason. It's not a visual bug, I saw my explorer and Workspace was empty. No errors in Output, and this only happens when my camera is scriptable. I had this issue for months, maybe even years. Why is that and how could I fix it?
Edit: Forgot to say, it only happens in client, while in server everything is there.

I had the same problem try disabling StreamingEnabled from Worksapce that worked for me.
Edit: You can also put your cameras in ReplicatedFirst so don't gets deleted.
Example
https://devforum.roblox.com/t/issue-with-parts-disappearing-in-studio/2478353
